# Array.push doesnt work fine

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS-SDK to describe all instances in a particular region. I have more than 100 instances. I have to make a list of instanceId, volumeId and the devicename of all the 100 instances.

My code looks like this. I expect 100 different instances in my **miniregionoregon.json** file. But all I get is one single instance getting repeated 100 times. I did console.log on **params** - this is good as I get 100 distinct value ste

But paramArray is the problematic one. **paramArray.push(param)** does not seem to have the desired result. I have been on it for almost an hour and I have decided that this definitely needs a fresh pair of eyes.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + 'region_oregon.json';

fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    var outerindex = 0;
    var params = {};
    var paramArray = [];

    (function getDataRecur() {

        if (outerindex > data.length - 1) {
            console.log(paramArray);
            var fs = require('fs');
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + 'miniregionoregon.json', JSON.stringify(paramArray), function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("The file was saved!");
                }
            });
        } else {
            var instances = data[outerindex].Instances;
            console.log('instances_length', instances.length);
            var innerindex = 0;

            (function getInstanceRecur() {
                if (innerindex > instances.length - 1) {
                    console.log('done reading instances');
                    return;
                } else {
                    //console.log(dataArr[innerindex].Instances[0].InstanceId);
                    console.log(innerindex);
                    params.InstanceId = instances[innerindex].InstanceId;
                    params.VolumeId = instances[innerindex].BlockDeviceMappings[0].Ebs.VolumeId;
                    params.Device = instances[innerindex].BlockDeviceMappings[0].DeviceName;

                    paramArray.push(params);

                    innerindex++;
                    getInstanceRecur();
                }
            }());


            outerindex++;
            getDataRecur();
        }
    }());


});
```

Comment: Is it the last one of the set that is getting repeated across the entire set? If so you have a scope issue. I'll provide a full explanation if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is only initialized once.  So, every time the lines

```
params.InstanceId = instances[innerindex].InstanceId;
params.VolumeId = instances[innerindex].BlockDeviceMappings[0].Ebs.VolumeId;
params.Device = instances[innerindex].BlockDeviceMappings[0].DeviceName;

paramArray.push(params);
```

run, they act on the same object - overwriting those 3 properties and then pushing another reference to the object onto the array.  You should instead initialize `params` right before setting those properties and pushing it.